# Calling Redis zunionstore from Lua with variable KEYS

Tags: scripting, lua, redis, in-memory-database, set-theory

I have a lua script that needs to call a zunionstore on a variable number of keys. 
I'm trying to execute the following code:

```
local args = redis.call("zrange", "weight", 0, -1, "WITHSCORES")
local r,w
local count = 0
local cmd = ' '
for i=1,#args,2 do
    cmd = cmd .. args[i] .. ":weight " -- building up a list of zsets
    count = count + 1
end
redis.call("zunionstore", "p2_test_set", count, cmd)
```

The important lines being:

```
cmd = cmd .. args[i] .. ":weight "
```

Which builds the list of keys, and the actual call:

```
redis.call("zunionstore", "p2_test_set", count, cmd)
```

However, when executing I get the following error:

```
redis-cli EVAL "$(cat p2.lua)" 0
(error) ERR Error running script (call to f_6dc6501103ea64a02798af1cc9132f8337cdcad4): @user_script:9: ERR syntax error
```

So, how do I pass a variable number of keys, computed within the lua script, to the redis.call("zunionstore"...) command?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried calling the script with actual arguments? In your example you aren't passing any so you're effectively calling zunionstore with no keys.

Comment: Hey - I don't know the keys at runtime, so I'm not sure how I'd pass them to the LUA script (if that's what you're asking ...)

Comment: What I meant is - are you sure 'weight' has anything in it?

Comment: Yes, verified that. Thanks though.

Comment: Sure - without actually testing (don't have my lappy w. me now) I'd venture a guess that passing args to zunionstore needs to be done with a table and not as a concatenated string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this is:

```
for i=0,#array,1 do
    local tmp = {'zunionstore', key, #array[i], unpack(array[i])}
    redis.call(unpack(tmp))
end
```