# Redis Lua: dynamic number of keys in redis call

Tags: lua, redis

I'm using a lua script to get a `ZINTERSTORE` result. What I want is to be able to give lua a dynamic number of zsets in the call such that:

```
redis.pcall('ZINTERSTORE', result, n, keys[1], keys[2], keys[3], keys[4], keys[5],  'AGGREGATE', 'MAX')
```

becomes something like:

```
redis.pcall('ZINTERSTORE', result, n, dynamic_key_list, 'AGGREGATE', 'MAX')
```

Lua's `table.getn` function lets me get the size `n`. Problem here is that if `dynamic_key_list` is a list, then redis cries loud and early with:

```
Lua redis() command arguments must be strings or integers
```

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027995/calling-redis-zunionstore-from-lua-with-variable-keys) possible solution but I don't want to iterate over the table and do the redis call every time, since I could potentially have 10-15 keys and it is an overhead I can't afford. Is there another way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to pass a lua array/table to a function that takes variable parameters, you need the `unpack` function.

```
-- put all arguments of redis.pcall into a lua array/table
local args = {'ZINTERSTORE', result, n}
for i, v in ipairs(dynamic_key_list) do
    table.insert(args, v)
end
table.insert(args, 'AGGREGATE')
table.insert(args, 'MAX')

-- unpack the table and pass to redis.pcall
redis.pcall(unpack(args))
```